# How does Google Analytics detect IP addresses?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, ip-address

I have searched on Google about how the IP address is detected using JavaScript, where all the sources inform me that it's not possible.
But Google Analytics is JavaScript snippet.
So, how does it exactly do it?

Answer (score 4):

Their JS causes the browser to make (several) HTTP requests to their servers. HTTP requests are transmitted over TCP/IP. This includes the IP address. It is their server side code that discovers the IP address, not the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible because the Google Analytics JS snippet makes requests to Google's servers—and Google can inspect that request and try to determine the IP address. So the detection is still happening on the server (as opposed to the client running the JS).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript by itself cannot get the ip address, but an ajax call to this address can return your ip address if that works for you.

http://freegeoip.net/json/

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://freegeoip.net/json/",
}).done(function(data) {
  alert(data.ip);
});
```